# My production environment SMTP doesn't work when deployed and I don't know what to do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, smtp

When I connect to the production environment through my git, my SMTP works, but when I connect through heroku it doesn't

I'm trying to make an app which everytime someone'd make a comment, an email would be sent.

When I connect through "rails s --environment=production" in git, everything works as expected, but when I deploy my app to heroku, I get an 500 "(Internal Server Error)" in my chrome console and nothing is sent.

-These are my **production action_mailer configurations**:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "warm-mesa-2622.herokuapp.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              =>  "smtp.interativasistemas.com",
    :port                 =>  587,
    :domain               =>  'warm-mesa-2622.herokuapp.com',
    :user_name            =>  'my_user@interativasistemas.com',
    :password             =>  <password>,
    :authentication       =>  'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto =>  true,
    :enable_ssl           =>  true,
    :openssl_verify_mode =>   'none'
  }
```

-This is the **log** from my **git connection** of when I create a new comment, which everything goes as expected:

```
Started POST "/jobs/15/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 15:33:19 -0300
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r4fDJrBWRjKgNqwMlfqRAzMZO8fPC
vjaPOxVfAghGb0=", "comment"=>{"name"=>"Comment", "body"=>"Comment Post."}, "comm
it"=>"Send", "job_id"=>"15"}
  Rendered company_mailer/new_comment.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered company_mailer/new_comment.text.erb (1.0ms)

Sent mail to mella.neto@gmail.com (1514ms)
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (15.0ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (20.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5192ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3509.2ms)
cache: [POST /jobs/15/comments] invalidate, pass
```

-This is the **same log** on my **heroku connection** which everything goes wrong, and the email isn't sent:

```
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:22.843252+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/jobs/15/com
ments" for 187.23.176.51 at 2014-08-22 18:37:22 +0000
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:22.845655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by CommentsCont
roller#create as JS
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:22.845725+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"��
�", "authenticity_token"=>"e07XWzBXlkYBLVXIhGMCxVhekzMpayaGXrUoTH2Xgco=", "comme
nt"=>{"name"=>"Comment", "body"=>"Comment Body."}, "commit"=>"Send", "job_id"=>"
15"}
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:22.866964+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered company_mailer/
new_comment.html.erb (0.6ms)
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:22.867544+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered company_mailer/
new_comment.text.erb (0.3ms)
←[33m2014-08-22T18:37:23.213749+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th="/jobs/15/comments" host=warm-mesa-2622.herokuapp.com request_id=15dba4d8-7b2
7-4cf0-9da8-ea0b117201c0 fwd="187.23.176.51" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=373m
s status=500 bytes=1274
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.203501+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.203508+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Sent mail to mella.neto@gm
ail.com (327ms)
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.203846+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 358ms
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205470+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205473+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Conne
ction refused - connect(2)):
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205475+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/comments
_controller.rb:7:in `create'
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205476+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205478+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-08-22T18:37:23.205798+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m cache: [POST /jobs/15/comm
ents] invalidate, pass
```

This is my my **comments_controller create function**:

```
  def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @comment = @job.comments.build(params[:comment])

    if success = @comment.save
      CompanyMailer.new_comment(@job, @comment).deliver
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if success
          flash[:notice] = "Comment was created with success!"
        else
          flash[:alert] = "Comment could not be created!"
        end
        redirect_to @job
      end
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And also my **company_mailer** which defines the email function:

```
class CompanyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "my_user@interativasistemas.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.company_mailer.new_comment.subject
  #
  def new_comment(job, comment)
    @job      = job
    @comment  = comment
    @company  = job.company

    mail to: @company.email, subject: "New comment received"
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me please ? I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

To debug problems like this, you want to create a one-off dyno with `heroku run bash` and then `rails s` or `rails console` from there.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos